# Mobile PDF reader with javascript support

Tags: pdf, mobile

I created a PDF with some javascript checks and input dialogs. It obiously works on the desktop version of Acrobat but it doesn't in the mobile (android) version.

I also tried Xodo and Google PDF Viewer...

Is there anything out there which behaves like the desktop counterpart? Preferably for IOS

Comment: I am one of the developers on Xodo. If you don't mind, could you file a ticket here. https://www.pdftron.com/support/reportproblem.html Please include the file you created (it is kept confidentially).

Comment: @Ryan Which product should I use? There is no Xodo

Comment: PDFNet SDK would be the correct one, but don't worry, I am expecting the ticket, so you can just link back to here if you like in the comments section. Same with other fields like company, you can omit as you like. Please also include information on how you created the PDF (e.g. software). thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The leaders of the pack are said to be PDFExpert by Readdle for iOS and qPDF Notes Pro by qoppa for Android.

Both vendors have the API information published, meaning that you can see which objects, methods and properties are supported.

And then you will have to program your form accordingly.